# Materialize chips - Case sensitive chips

Tags: materialize

Materialize chips component does not allow duplicates with same case (lowercase/uppercase)

However, how can we achieve the same for case sensitive chips?
i.e, the user should not be able to type in chips like "abc" and "ABC"

```js
$('.chips-placeholder').material_chip({
    placeholder: 'Enter a tag',
    secondaryPlaceholder: '+Add more tags',
});
```

```html
    <!--Added external styles and scripts-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!--Html body-->
    
    <div class="chips chips-placeholder"></div>
```